# How can I get a UWP XAML page to detect when the % symbol is pressed

Tags: xaml, uwp

Still a relatively new programmer. Working on a project for school involving a magstripe reader. I need to find a way to get the page to listen for when a % key is pressed as magstripes put out %B before the card number.

Thanks

```
private void Page_KeyDown(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey."UNSURE OF HOW TO GET THE % SYMBOL")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in a couple ways:

1. Detect when the `%` key is press by detecting if `Shift` key is down and the `5` key is pressed (this may not work with non-English keyboard layouts).

You can implement this by adding an `if` statement in your `Page_KeyDown` method to check if the Shift is pressed, and then set a `private bool IsShiftPressed` variable to be `true` so you can remember it. Then, when a second key is pressed by the user, you can check if `IsShiftPressed` is `true` and if the new key being pressed is the `5` key.

2. Detect when a new character is entered into the text field and handle the situations when that character is `%`. You'd use the `TextBox.TextChanging` event here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textchanging.